# Unity - creating a hovercar by counteracting gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wish to implement a way to create a hoverbike. 
my current code to hover is

```
readonly float yForce = 80;
Physics.Raycast(hoverbike.transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit);
Debug.Log(hit.distance);
if (hit.distance < 10 && hit.distance > 0)
{
   if (hoverbike.velocity.y < 0.1)
    {
        hoverbike.AddForce(0, yForce, 0, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        Debug.Log("applying force!");
    }
}
```

This works, but not well, the vehicle bounces up and down. I also tried to subtract the exact same force as the bike's `y velocity`, but the vehicle slowly drifted down, and did not go up to my desired height of 10 units from the ground. How can I achieve this?
Simply counteracting its current velocity is easy, but how do I make it float back *up* to the desired height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier to simply turn off gravity than to constantly be fighting against it; this frequent readjustment is likely the cause of your bounciness. Upon bike activation you can take the object's `y velocity` calculations fully into your own hands as so:

```
public class Bike : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody hoverbike;
    private bool isBikeActive = false;

    [SerializeField] private float verticalSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float hoverHeight = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float hoverTolerance = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float maximumVerticalVelocity = 10f;

    private void Awake()
    {
        hoverbike = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) { ToggleBike(); }

        if (isBikeActive)
        {
            Physics.Raycast(hoverbike.transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit);

            Vector3 modifiedVelocity = hoverbike.velocity;

            if ((hit.distance > hoverHeight - hoverTolerance) && (hit.distance < hoverHeight + hoverTolerance))
            {
                modifiedVelocity.y = 0f;
            }
            else
            {
                modifiedVelocity.y = -(hit.distance - hoverHeight) * verticalSpeedMultiplier;
                modifiedVelocity.y = Mathf.Clamp(modifiedVelocity.y, -maximumVerticalVelocity, maximumVerticalVelocity);
            }

            Debug.Log($"Distance from ground: {hit.distance}, Bike Velocity.y: {modifiedVelocity}");
            hoverbike.velocity = modifiedVelocity;
        }
    }

    private void ToggleBike()
    {
        isBikeActive = !isBikeActive;
        hoverbike.useGravity = !isBikeActive;
    }
}
```

Your bike will now always try to move towards the point `hoverHeight` units above the object below it, until it is within `hoverTolerance` from that point. It will also move much more smoothly towards this point, moving faster the further away it is from the intended height.

If you wish for the bike to still bob up and down a little, this can be achieved by modifying the `hoverHeight` slowly over time, perhaps through use of a Sine function.

Comment: By setting the velocity, it means that brief but sufficiently powerful impacts that would push the bike upwards or downwards (like explosions) will be completely or almost completely ignored.

Comment: @Ruzihm I've added a maximum velocity now to prevent issues with large drops/high values of hoverHeight. As for collisions one could consider adding additional raycasts to push the bike away from the obstacles if that became an issue, but this is perhaps outside the scope of the question as asked.

Answer (score 1):

## Hovering is (essentially) a visual effect

Make the collider extend below the vehicle so that when it rests on the ground the bike *appears* to be hovering at the desired height. The physics engine only does physics. It doesn't care about what those colliders are, it just wants them to behave in a physics-y way, and if that means falling until it reaches the ground, then let them fall until they reach the ground. Take advantage of the physics engine instead of going around it and then trying to solve the bugs created by going around the physics engine.

Comment: One problem with this approach is that if you want the vehicle to tilt and bounce in reaction to collisions, you would have to alter the relative position/rotation/size of the collider to allow the bike to move closer to the ground.

Comment: @Ruzihm Sounds like a great use for `Spring`s.

Answer (score 1):

First, apply your dampening force scaled by the downward velocity, then apply an additional force scaled by how far it needs to travel back upwards. Keep track of how much force/acceleration you apply through this process and cap that amount at some constant.

```
readonly float yForce = 80f; // requires tuning
readonly float dampenFactor = 0.8f; // requires tuning
readonly float offsetFactor = 0.5f; // requires tuning

readonly float targetHeight = 10f

Physics.Raycast(hoverbike.transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit);
Debug.Log(hit.distance);
if (hit.distance < targetHeight && hit.distance > 0)
{
    float availableForce = yForce;

    // cancel out downward velocity
    if (hoverbike.velocity.y < 0)
    {
        // Cap out upward force based on yForce
        float cappedDampenForce = Mathf.Min(dampenFactor * -hoverbike.velocity.y,
                availableForce);

        // How much force is available for the offset?
        availableForce -= cappedDampenForce;

        hoverbike.AddForce(Vector3.up * cappedDampenForce, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        Debug.Log("applied dampening force");
    }

    // Find upward force scaled by distance left to target height, and cap that amount
    float cappedOffsetForce = Mathf.Min(offsetFactor * (targetHeight - hit.distance), 
            availableForce);

    hoverbike.AddForce(Vector3.up * cappedOffsetForce, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    Debug.Log("applied offset force");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This is great, however, I went with pika's approach because it was much simpler, especially for me. Doesn't mean your answer wasn't just as good, the other one just suited me better.

Comment: @KatalystPrime That's absolutely more than fair! :) I did just notice a shortcoming in pika's answer and commented on it so be aware of that.